# FileSystemWatcher Raising Multiple Events

Tags: c#, logging, filesystemwatcher

I'm going to start off by apologizing if this is a duplicated question. There were a ton of FileSystemWatcher questions but I didn't see any that addressed my issue.

Ok, so I have a console application in C# that is monitoring a directory, which we will call `Root`. `Root` has many subfolders. The purpose of this application is to write to a log file if any .csv files are create, modified, or deleted within `Root` or any of its subfolders. I currently have this working fine, sort of. The only problem is that when a .csv file is created, modified, or deleted it actually raises the event for all 3.

For example, if I create a file in `Root` called `test.csv`, the log file would look like this:

```
 10/04/2012: File F:/Root/test.csv Created
 10/04/2012: File F:/Root/test.csv Changed
 10/04/2012: File F:/Root/test.csv Created
 10/04/2012: File F:/Root/test.csv Deleted
```

I'm not sure whats going on, so here is the code that sets up the `FileSystemWatcher`

```
 _watchFolder.Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootToWatch"];
 _watchFolder.Filter = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileNameToWatch"];
 _watchFolder.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName 
                             | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
 _watchFolder.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
 _watchFolder.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
 _watchFolder.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
 _watchFolder.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
 _watchFolder.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

 try
 {
     _watchFolder.EnableRaisingEvents = true; 
 }
 catch (ArgumentException ex)
 {
     AbortMonitoring(ex.Message);
 }
```

And here is my OnChanged event (Renamed is same but has different argument)

```
  protected static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //compile message to insert into log file.
        string message = "File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType;
        UpdateLogFile(message);
    }
```

Comment: Getting all three suggests to me the code that's creating them is doing a rename. Rename will give you a delete, then a create, then a write when it gets filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a handler only for the `changed` event. It should gather all change types. The other types of events like `created` are there if you want the event to be raised only on a particular change type.

```
watchFolder.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
_watchFolder.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
```

Comment: Actually, I just tried this and with only the `.Changed` event I get no events raised. Not even a "file changed" event.